# Why is the gcloud command line tool so much faster than a browser upload?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Today, I was uploading a 1.55gb zip file to a gcloud instance. I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) and used the upload file command from a browser window.

[image]

After getting frustrated this was taking too long (I waited for an hour and it said it was 12% done), I looked elsewhere in the tutorial and used the following command from my local terminal

`gcloud compute scp [FILE-NAME]  [INSTANCE-NAME]:/tmp/`

Where the file uploaded in ~1 minute and 7 seconds (as opposed to an estimated 10 or so hours for the other method).

Why was the `scp` method so much faster? I don't see an explanation in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files, and intuitively, couldn't the `upload` command just run the `scp` command under the hood?

Comment: Its a good question. I don't know if the upload file mechanism in Cloud Shell uses scp or something completely different.  It may be that using Upload file performs sequences of HTTP posts of base64 encoded data from within the browser environment.  There may be a dramatic distinction in path length and implementation.    That all said, I like your question and would be curious to hear guidance on when Upload file from Cloud Shell is a worthy component as opposed to scp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser uses IAP tunneling, which is much slower than a direct SSH connection.

Note: Using the browser (IAP Tunneling) for file transfers is not recommended as there are data quotas. This is a convenience feature that is not designed for your use case.

Using an IAP tunnel does provide a useful benefit. Your Compute Engine instance does not need a public IP address. You can reach instances with only private IP addresses.

Browsers cannot launch programs such as scp.

The best method is to install an SSH/SCP product to do file transfers. I use Bitvise on Windows.

Here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding) for more information about IAP Tunneling (TCP Forwarding).

Comment: Thanks! I figured it had something to do with being browser-based. They should really mention in the docs that it's not recommended for larger file transfers.

Comment: good point, I'm submitting a change to the docs to make this clearer.